# How to pass NSDate as a pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsdate

In my application I have storyboard, and a lot of segues to view controller with date picker.

How can I pass `NSDate`, as a pointer, to keep value in this `NSDate`object, after selection will made?

Now, in my `AppDelegate` properties, I have a lot of NSDate's. And in `prepareForSegue` I pass the right `NSDate`to view controller as a retain property:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate * date;
```

After selection is made, I assign value to this property:

```
- (IBAction)dateChanged:(id)sender{
    if (date) {
        date = datePicker.date;
    }
}
```

But it is not working.

Where I was wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are describing is called pass-by-reference in Objective-C parlance. Since variables of object type are already pointers, you need a pointer-pointer type. To implement this you would pass an `NSDate **dateReference` to your date picker controller. After picking the date the controller would set `*dateReference = pickedDate`.

But that's an uncommon and fragile way to pass back the picked date. A better way would be to use a delegate on the date picker controller with a protocol that supports date picking.

Or, even better in this simple case, use a block based API: The date picker controller gets a completionBlock that the client controller would set before presenting the date picker.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than:

```
date = datePicker.date
```

use:

```
self.date = datePicker.date
```

Similarly, refer to self.date.  For more, see [Setting an Objective-C class property without using a self reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295702/setting-an-objective-c-class-property-without-using-a-self-reference).

Comment: This would still only set the ivar in the date picker controller, not in the client controller's.

Comment: Ah, OK. I misunderstood the question then.